# GWT 2.4 Integration With Spring

Tags: spring, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm currently Working  on a GWT 2.4 / Spring 3 application and want to use the RequestFactory API to communicate with Spring services.

Beginning from GWT 2.4, I saw that there is some changes to the RequestFactoryServlet (The Addition for the ThreadLocal), how Can I easily Integrate them ?? I don't use ActiveRecord Style but DAO/Service.

I searched and find that to integrate GWT integrate with Spring beginning from 2.4 you just need to create a custom ServiceLocator that expose your Spring beans.

```
public class SpringServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
            RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalServletContext());
    return context.getBean(clazz);
}
```

}

And you need to configure you RequestFactoryServlet as mentioned on the Google documentation.

I followed theses steps but my when GWT client make a Request to the Back-end i receive this Exception :

```
    Sep 13, 2011 7:42:34 AM com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet doPost
SEVERE: Unexpected error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:425)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:217)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:125)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /gwtRequest (127.0.0.1) 1420 bytes
```

Did I miss something on the configuration ??

Comment: Can you post your configuration of RequestFactoryServlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the Problem, It was because I wasn't using the GWT 2.4 libraries on the Lib Folder.

I did write a little article which describe clearly how to integrate Spring With GWT 2.4 => http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/spring-gwt-integration-using-the-requestfactory-api/